# Which is the difference between "model_zoo.load_url" and "state_dict"

Tags: model, pytorch, resnet, state-dict

```
model_urls = {
    'resnet18': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet18-5c106cde.pth',
    'resnet34': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet34-333f7ec4.pth',
    'resnet50': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet50-19c8e357.pth',
    'resnet101': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet101-5d3b4d8f.pth',
    'resnet152': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet152-b121ed2d.pth',
}

args.dataset == 'cifar100' or args.dataset == 'cifar10':
args.stride = [2, 2]
resnet = resnet18(args, pretrained=False, num_classes=args.num_classes)
initial_weight = model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['resnet18'])
local_model = resnet 
initial_weight_1 = local_model.state_dict() 

for key in initial_weight.keys():
    if key[0:3] == 'fc.' or key[0:5]=='conv1' or key[0:3]=='bn1':
        initial_weight[key] = initial_weight_1[key] 

local_model.load_state_dict(initial_weight)
```

I dont understand this line " initial_weight[key] = initial_weight_1[key]"

Could you please tell me why we need to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Function [`torch.utils.model_zoo.load_url`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/model_zoo.html) will load the serialized torch object from the given URL. In this particular case the URL used hosts the model's weight dictionary for the *ResNet18* network.

Therefore `initial_weight` is the dictionary containing the weights of a pretrained *ResNet18*, while `initial_weight_1` is the dictionary of the weights on the current model `resnet` in memory initialized by `resnet18`.

The following lines will go through the layers of the `resnet` model and copy the weights loaded from that URL if the `key[0:3] == 'fc.' or key[0:5]=='conv1' or key[0:3]=='bn1':` condition is met.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, initial_weight is the weight of the pre-train ResNet18, while initial_weight_1 is just the structure of the ResNet 18 and not contain any pre-trained parameters, right? If so, why need to copy from initial_weight_1 to initial_weight to cover the pre-trained parameters. Thanks a lot~